# Meaning of this jquery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, comments

In **[`jquery-3.1.0.min.js`](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js)** there's a line that has a statement `//,Fb={},` and followed by a lot of more statements Doesn't `//` make everything else a comment? then why are the statements present after it?

Comment: it's not in **jquery-3.1.0.js** it is in **jquery-3.1.0.min.js** and it's not the start of a line, read the code thoroughly to understand why that **isn't** a comment prefix ... `Eb=/^\/\//,Fb={}`

Comment: @JaromandaX my ide has recognised it as a comment. Just to know,it isn't comment then?

Comment: @NarayanasamiN No it's not, it's a regular expression.

Comment: Perhaps your IDE can't deal with the long lines in a minified file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above `//,Fb={},` is not a commented code, but `//` here is a part of regular expresion :

```
Eb=/^\/\//,Fb={},...
___^_____^
```

Hope this helps.